Procedimientos almacenados SQLite para desarrollo de aplicación en C#
como podría utilizar este procedimiento almacenado en SQLite?
//Este procedimiento es en SQLServer. Lo que hace es mostrar a los contratistas que comiencen su nombre con la inicial que recibe el procedimiento (@LETRA)

CREATE PROC SP_AGENDACONTRATISTA (@LETRA CHAR(1))
AS
 SELECT C.IDE_CON AS CODIGO,
 C.NOM_CON+SPACE(1)+C.PAT_CON+SPACE(1)+C.MAT_CON AS CONTRATISTA,
 C.FON_CON AS TELEFONO,
 C.EMA_CON AS CORREO
 FROM CONTRATISTA C
 WHERE C.NOM_CON LIKE @LETRA+"%"
GO

Estuve buscando y al parecer SQLite no soporta procedimientos almacenados, encontré esta página que habla sobre esto y da unas alternativas https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-sqlite/  el problema es que no pude adaptarlo, e hice algo como esto
CREATE FUNCTION CONTRATISTAS(LETRA CHAR(1)) RETURNS TEXT AS 
BEGIN
       DECLARE NOM_CON TEXT
       SELECT NOM_CON, PAT_CON, MAT_CON  INTO FROM CONTRATISTA WHERE NOM_CON LIKE LETRA + "%"
       RETURN NOM_CON;
END;

Adicional quiero agregar que estoy usando SQLite para un desarrollo en C#, por lo que también leí en algunas paginas que es posible hacer algo similar a un stored procedure desde código, pero los ejemplos que encontré eran para python, por favor, si saben como podría hacerlo en código estaré agradecido.
Gracias.

Pero ese SP no hace nada importante.. solo copia el sql y ejecutalo desde el programa.... y pasa el parametro y listo.... y no, sqlite es una mini base que no tiene casi nada mas que sql basico...
